# Getting physical sector of a filesystem directory entry

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems

Is there a way to know the sector/cluster number a directory entry in Window?
If there's a separate or absent solution for NTFS/FAT32, it's ok, I can live with it.

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364572.aspx) is what you are after.  I also found a really detailed [exploration](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/luserland.htm) of its use.